# Android: Homescreen Icons different than Menu Icons

Tags: android

Is it possible in Android to declare a HomescreenIcon for the user e.g. colored and inside the application the same Icon shown in the Action Bar just white?

In my case these are two different images i want to show. I defined the icon inside the AndroidManifest.xml but i can not find any option to change it for the ActionBar. It is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`android:logo`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#logo) in your manifest to provide the action bar image and [`android:icon`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#icon) to provide home screen icon. Both of them should be set to a drawable resource and can point to a different resources.